# Entity Framework Object Disposed Exception when adding record

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have the following records:

```
public class Group
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }            

    [NotMapped]
    public IEnumerable<Item>? Items { get; set; }   
    public Item? Main { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public virtual int Id { get => base.Id ; set => base.Id = value; }

    [NotMapped]
    public IEnumerable<Group>? Groups { get; set; }

}
```

The configure method looks like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Group>()
       .HasMany(g => g.Items)
       .WithMany(u => u.Groups)
       .UsingEntity(j => j.ToTable("GroupItems"));

    modelBuilder.Entity<Group>()
       .HasOne(a => a.Main);
```

In the following code, I'm trying to insert a record into the `Groups` table:

```
public async Task<Group> CreateGroup(string name, int id)
{
    var mainItem = await dbContext.Items
            .SingleAsync(a => a.Id == id);

    var group = new Group()
    {
        Name = name,
        Main = mainItem
    };

    await dbContext.Groups
        .AddAsync(group); // Crashes here
    int result = await dbContext
        .SaveChangesAsync();

    return group;
}
```

The line marked above crashes with the following exception:

> System.ObjectDisposedException   HResult=0x80131622   Message=Cannot
> access a disposed context instance. A common cause of this error is
> disposing a context instance that was resolved from dependency
> injection and then later trying to use the same context instance
> elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are calling
> 'Dispose' on the context instance, or wrapping it in a using
> statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the
> dependency injection container take care of disposing context
> instances. ObjectDisposed_ObjectName_Name

The app is riddled with examples of similar configuration that work fine. The only possible culprit I can imagine is that the fact that each of the classes references the other is causing it to crash, however, since this is a many-to-many relationship (i.e. An `item` can be in more than one `group`, each `group` can have more than one `item`, and each group has a main `item`), this was the only way that I could see EF allowing me to set that up.

Can someone point me in the right direction - especially if there's some debugging technique that I'm unaware of.  I've switched data logging on:

```
public static void ConfigureServices(this IServiceCollection services,
                                     string connectionString) =>
    services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(a =>
    {
        a.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
        a.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
    });
```

But it doesn't tell me anything, other than the queries that are executing on the DB, and I suspect this is an EF quirk.

Comment: Can you post the entire class containing the creategroup method. Somewhere your context is getting disposed

Comment: @Immorality -  Surely, if that were the case, the very first line would throw the exception?

Comment: How do you call the `CreateGroup` method? You may have forgotten `await`.

Comment: I believe the error may arise from the use of [AddAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.addasync?view=efcore-7.0#microsoft-entityframeworkcore-dbcontext-addasync(system-object-system-threading-cancellationtoken)) the EF core documentation says it's discouraged but does not suggest why it would cause this issue. However, the source code is perhaps revealing as to why: see [DbContext.cs#L1272](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/main/src/EFCore/DbContext.cs#L1272)

Comment: Turns out I was missing an await - sorry, I thought I'd checked them all!